# intersection of four linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra

If A > 0 , c, d, u, v are non zero constants, and the graphs of $f(x)=|Ax +c| +d $ and 
$g(x)=-|Ax +u| +v$ intersect exactly at two points (1, 4) and (3, 1), then the value of $\frac{u+c}{A}$ 
 equals

Comment: The intersecting line is of opposite slope viz A and -A

Comment: but For each line we have two linear equation. One will intersect and the other will not intersect that is my cobfusion

Comment: The graph of $f$ is a V-shape pointing down. The graph of $g$ is an upside-down V-shape pointing up. Because the rays of $f$ are parallel to the rays of $g$ (the RH ray of $f$ is parallel to the LH ray of $g$ and vice versa, because both have $A$ as the coefficient of $x$), The only way this intersection can happen is if the LH ray of $f$ intersects the LH ray of $g$ and the RH ray of $f$ intersects the RH ray of $g$. So you know exactly with line of $f$ to intersect with which line of $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the following graphical representation (we have taken here $A=3$, but $A$ could take any value $>1.5$) :

[image]

We see that the first point $(x,y)=(1,4)$ being at the intersection of lines :

$$\begin{cases}y&=& \ \ \ Ax+u+v\\y&=&-Ax-c+d\end{cases} \ \ \implies \ \ 
\begin{cases}4&=& \ \ \ A+u+v\\4&=&-A-c+d\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

For the second pair of lines and the second point $(x,y)=(3,1)$

$$\begin{cases}y&=&-Ax-u+v\\y&=& \ \ \ Ax+c+d\end{cases} \ \ \implies \ \ 
\begin{cases}1&=&-3A-u+v\\1&=& \ \ \ 3A+c+d\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

The $2+2$ equations in (1) and (2) involving $c,d,u,v,A$ give

$$\begin{cases}c &=&- 3/2- 2A \\
d &=& \ \ \ 5/2 - A\\
u &=&\ \ \ 3/2 - 2A\\
v &=&\ \ \ 5/2+A \end{cases}$$

Therefore :

$$\dfrac{u+c}{A}=-4$$

Comment: No comment ? ....